# How to write dynamic SQL for a function that has dynamic SQL parameter?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, dynamic-text, dijkstra, postgresql-10

I am trying to **execute a string SQL query in function** i.e.

```
Create or Replace Function Route(edge_table text)
Returns table(sequence integer) as $$
Begin
Return Query Execute 'with r as(
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra( ' || '''SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ' || edge_table || ' ''' || ', 7, 12, false, false );
)
select seq from r';
End;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

When I run function gets created, but when I call this function it says verify your query is not correct.

Actually dijkstra takes an string sql.like that,

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost 
FROM pgr_dijkstra( **'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table'**, 7, 12, false, false );
```

I want table name to be **dynamic**, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post the exact and complete error message

Comment: Generally, if you want to use a dynamic table name, it is better to use execute format. See, for example, [this answer on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/dynamically-generated-table-name-in-postgresql-copy-command/5281790#5281790).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a semicolon that shouldn't be there in the textual expression to be executed (`...  7, 12, false, false );`), causing the reminder of the expression to be ignored (`select seq from r`).

Try removing it

```
Returns table(sequence integer) as $$
Begin
Return Query Execute 'with r as(
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost FROM pgr_dijkstra( ' || '''SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ' || edge_table || ' ''' || ', 7, 12, false, false )
)
select seq from r';
End;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Also, use the concat operator, it is much easier to follow than all those ||, imho.